# s3 access triggers in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, triggers, cloud

I want to create a s3 trigger that calls an api when someone tries to access/download a file stored in s3.

I saw some usecases for s3 trigger only for creating and deleting files. But couldnot find triggers when someone tries to access a file from s3.

Comment: Amazon S3 does not have a trigger to intercept, or respond to, access attempts. Can I ask... _Why_ are you looking for this capability? Can you tell us more about what goal you would like to achieve? For example, are you wanting to block access in some situations, or perhaps log access attempts? Please tell us more and we might be able to offer an alternative approach.

Comment: I am trying to build a data platform that makes data accessible to people. People can directly access data from s3 links or through the platform. I want to keep track of data access not just through my platform but also through s3 links.

Comment: When you say "keep track of data access", would [Logging requests using server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) be sufficient? It can provide log files of requests to S3 buckets.

Comment: No, I need to execute some functions when someone tries to access the data from s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not provide the ability to intercept requests, but you could **send requests via Amazon CloudFront** and [Use AWS Lambda with CloudFront Lambda@Edge - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) to intercept the calls and determine what to do. Lambda@Edge functions are limited in what they can do and how long they can run.

Alternatively, you could send the requests to your own API endpoint (eg using API Gateway or a Lambda URL). You can then write code that examines the request and determines what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudtrial for that as explained in [Logging Amazon S3 API calls using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-logging.html). So you would settup a trial in CloudTrial to monitor `GetObject` S3 event objects, which you can then detect as events in AWS EventBridge.

Other possibility would be through [S3 Object Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-s3-object-lambda.html).